# case matching on a value from dev.config in Phoenix (Elixir)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to make simple token authentication in Phoenix (Elixir) controller. The value of correct token is stored in `config/dev.secrets.exs`

so far I got this working:

`POST https:www.myapp.com/notification?token=123`

```
defmodule Myapp.NotificationController do
  use Myapp.Web, :controller

  def create(conn, params) do
    etoken = endpoint_token()

    case params["token"] do
      etoken ->
        # ....
        conn |> send_resp(201, "")
      _ ->
        conn|> send_resp(401, "Not Authorized")
  end

  defp endpoint_token, do: Application.get_env(:myapp, :notification)[:endpoint_token]
end
```

It works but it just don't feel right. I first need to call the method `endpoint_token()` and save it to variable `etoken` and only then I can do `case` comparison. Is there a cleaner way to write this ??

Now I would ideally like the `endpoint_token` method to stay method as I would like to extract it out to module that will be used on some other places

**update**

BTW this way I'm keep on getting/not getting (randomly) this warning:

```
warning: variable "etoken" is unused
  web/controllers/notification_controller.ex:8

warning: variable "etoken" is unused
  web/controllers/notification_controller.ex:1
```

Comment: You are getting that warning because you are rebinding etoken in the case. You are not matching it as I explained below. So, the first binding is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code as it is written does not work. You will bind the value in `params["token"]` in the case. You need to use the pin operator to do a match `^etoken`. But now to answer your question...

Why don't you just use an if statement?

```
  def create(conn, params) do
    if params["token"] == endpoint_token() do
        # ....
        conn |> send_resp(201, "")
    else
        conn|> send_resp(401, "Not Authorized")
    end
  end
```

EDIT:

If you really wanted to use a case here, you could flip the case.

```
  def create(conn, %{"token" => token}) do
    case endpoint_token() do
      ^token -> 
        # ....
        conn |> send_resp(201, "")
       _ ->
        conn|> send_resp(401, "Not Authorized")
    end
  end
```

Comment: that's really nice, thank you, honestly I didn't know Elixir has If statements :) good to know. I've finished the Phoenix book, I need to read the Dave Thomas Elixir book ASAP as I'm getting kicked at basic language features like these :)

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of people starting with Phoenix before they have the basics of Elixir. I did that with Rails. However, Elixir is a little more difficult to pick up than Ruby, if your coming from an OO background. I highly recommend you can Dave's book. It will save you a lot of time :) Good luck